# Display the selected value of listview in the textview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and textview in Activty When I click a value in a listview, that selected item will display in a textivew.
I have attached my sample code,please help me.

[image]

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView txt_disp;
ListView lv;
String fruits[]={"Apple","Orange","Banana","Grapes","kiwi"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt_disp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     ArrayList<SamplePOJO> searchResults = GetSearchResults();
        CustomAdapter ea=new CustomAdapter(this, searchResults);
             lv.setAdapter(ea);
    // here i need to set the text(txt_display)  
}  }

CustomAdapter.java
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.fruit=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fruit);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.fruit.setText(ContactArrayList.get(position).getFruit());
    holder.fruit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String dis=holder.fruit.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("Selected Text:"+dis);
                 //Selected text value  set into textview in MainActivity 
    }
    });
    return convertView;
  }
```

Comment: Hi FaddishWorm, I have shown a list view consists of items such as Banana, Grapes etc.. if i click on any of the item the same should be displayed in my text view as shown above. See the perspective is the both are in same activity, kindly do the favor Thanks in advance

Comment: try  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044119/display-the-selected-value-of-listview-in-the-textview/19044358#19044358) code copy and paste in your oncreate method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your CustomAdapter, define a TextView field and a setter for it, then in the onCreate set the textField to the textfield you pulled using findviewbyid

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView txt_disp;
ListView lv;
String fruits[]={"Apple","Orange","Banana","Grapes","kiwi"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt_disp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     ArrayList<SamplePOJO> searchResults = GetSearchResults();
        CustomAdapter ea=new CustomAdapter(this, searchResults);
             lv.setAdapter(ea);
    // here i need to set the text(txt_display)
ea.setTextField(txt_disp);


}  }

CustomAdapter.java

TextView textView;

public void setTextField(TextView tv){textView = tv;}
enter code here
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.fruit=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fruit);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.fruit.setText(ContactArrayList.get(position).getFruit());
    holder.fruit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String dis=holder.fruit.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("Selected Text:"+dis);
                 //Selected text value  set into textview in MainActivity
            textView.setText("Selected Text:"+dis);
    }
    });
    return convertView;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to listen to the item click event of the list 
You can do this by adding this code segment

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // set the value to the text view here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try:</s>

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String dis=holder.fruit.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Selected Text:"+dis);

    MainActivity.this.txt_disp.setText(dis);
 }
});
```

**EDIT :**

I didn't notice that those are separate classes. Try to set on ListViev click listener in Activity You will get position of selected item and items array.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        txt_disp.setText(fruits[position]);
    }
});
```

Comment: this won't work unless CustomAdapter is a subclass of the MainActivity, which is not the case here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                txt_disp.setText(fruits[arg2]);
            }
        });
```